# What annotation to use to define HTTP Request headers?

Tags: swagger, swagger-2.0

I've been searching the documentation but I can only find a annotation for Response request headers, but what is the annotation to use to define Request Headers?

Comment: Do you write the OpenAPI (Swagger) YAML/JSON definition manually? Or do you mean source code annotations? If it's the latter, please specify what language/framework you are using - Swashbuckle, Springfox, Swagger-PHP, etc.

Comment: Swagger with Restlet